# NSMutableArray containsObject returns true, but it shouldnt

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, contains

I found similar questions, but `-containsObject` is not working like I expect.

My problem is the `NSMutableArray -containsObject` method returns true when it shouldn't,
when trying to generate random UNIQUE colors and add to an array.

What is the best way to check if `NSMutableArray` contains an object with same values.

```
NSMutableArray *color_arr=[NSMutableArray array];
UIColor *t;
for(int i=0; i<100; i+=1)
{
    int r = arc4random()%256;
    int g = arc4random()%256;
    int b = arc4random()%256;

    t=[UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:255];

    if (![color_arr  containsObject:t])
    [color_arr addObject:t];

    //[t release];//is t need to be released here on non-arc project? well Im not sure. 
}
NSLog(@"total:%d",[color_arr count]);
```

---

The `NSLog()` always says array count is 1.

Comment: Did you debug to step through and look at `t` and the contents of `colour_arr`?

Comment: (UIColor*)t gets different address and rgb values as it should.
but containsObject says hey "I got it already."

just copy-paste code. and get log counts 1

Comment: UIColor takes floats (CGFloats to be precise) as RGB values - between 0 and 1. You probably have created a long series of identical objects by saturating the RGB values.

Comment: ahha! this is the problem. any similar class like UIColor that takes values 0-255 ?

Comment: No, but you can divide the value by 255.0. Or, if really important, write a category method that does it.

Comment: You commented out the release line. Which is right. Just letting you know that objects created with a "non init" method (in your case colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha: instead of [[UIColor alloc]init] are already "autoreleased" and will be deallocated automatically when they go out of scope. In your case they are retained by the array you're adding them into, so as long as the array is around, they will be around. But again, your array was not created with an init method, it is also autoreleased, and so at the end of that method it will be deallocated as well.

Comment: I edited my code below as well. Please see the new edit. Your for loop isn't constructed right. You declared *t too soon. Thus, you kept changing the value of *t instead of creating a new color object. So the array already DID have *t inside of it. YOu just kept changing *t. Declare the color once you are inside the for loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New Edit:

The structure of your `for()` loop is wrong too. You are declaring the UIColor before the loop begins. You should be declaring the color AFTER the loop begins:

```
for (i=0;i<100;i++) {
    int rInt = arc4random()%256;
    float rFloat = (float)rInt/255.0f;
    //same with gInt, bInt
    //make gFloat and bFloat this way
    UIColor *t = [UIColor colorWithRed:rFloat green:gFloat blue:bFloat alpha:1];
    if (![color_arr containsObject:t]) {
        [color_arr addObject:t];
    }
    NSLog(@"%i",color_arr.count);
}
```

UIColor doesn't use `integer` values, it uses `float` values.  Try dividing your `integer` by 255 and then setting those as r, g, b.

Like:

```
int rInt = arc4random()%256;
float rFloat = (float)rInt/255.0f;
//same with gInt, bInt
//make gFloat and bFloat this way
t = [UIColor colorWithRed:rFloat green:gFloat blue:bFloat alpha:1];
```

Comment: You'd probably want to set the alpha value to 1.0, too.