# Obj C - NSMutableArray containsObject return true

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

`NSMutableArray` `containsObject` returns true even the address and data is different.

I've seen this post [NSMutableArray containsObject returns true, but it shouldnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338352/nsmutablearray-containsobject-returns-true-but-it-shouldnt)
 already but still I'm not finding my solution:

Below is my scenario:

```
    NSMutableArray *destClasses = [NSMutableArray array];
    id sourceClasses = [dict objectForKey:@"Classes"];
    if ([sourceClasses isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
                for (NSDictionary *class in sourceClasses) {
                    MyClass *a = [[MyClass alloc] init];
                    [a arrangeClassWithDictionary:classDict]; //this methods assigns value to a from classDict
                    if (![destClasses containsObject:a]) {
                        [destClasses addObject:a];
                    }
                }
            }
```

In the first iteration `destClasses` adds an `MyClass` object and on the second iteration `[destClasses containsObject:a]` returns `true` even though the `a` has different address and different values assigned.

What I'm doing wrong here. Please help.

Comment: From `containsObject`: "Objects are considered equal if isEqual: returns YES." Did you override `isEqual:`? Do you have a working example where you reproduce the issue? What about, if it exists, using `indexOfObject:`, retrieve the object, and compare them with `isEqual:`?

Comment: I’m not overriding!! I’ve 2 values in dictionary but when I append object in array it just adds the final one, all the values in dictionary are similar expect one property.

Comment: @PrabaSaran - edit your question and include enough code to demonstrate... see [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

> `containsObject`: which sends the `isEqual:` message to every object it
>   contains with your object as the argument. It does not use `==` unless
>   the implementation of `isEqual:` relies on `==`.

I've to override the `isEqual:` method to provide equality checking for my object fields like below,

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    BOOL result = NO;

    if ([class isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {
        MyClass *otherObject = object;
        result = [self.name isEqualToString:[otherObject name]];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Note: if you override `isEqual` you should also override `hash` (see docs of both).